# Show only current category’s products in Product View

Tags: magento

I’ve been struggling with this question for a long time and it seems very easy to solve, I just can’t do it by myself.

Take a look at this page: http://adegean.dominiotemporario.com/porcelanas-brancas/artigos-de-mesa/linha-americana/saladeira-pequena-americana.html

This product is associated with 2 different categories, and I would like to show only a list of products of this current category (in this case, ID 188), not from all the cats the product is listed in. It’s just something like filtering this list by “current_cat_Id” or something.

The current code is this:

```
    <div class="box base-mini mini-related-items">     
     <?php 

     $test = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId();
     echo 'Current Main Category of this product this list should show:'.$test;

     ?>


     <?php

      if ($_product) {
        // get collection of categories this product is associated with
        $categories =$_product->getCategoryCollection()

       //->setPage(1, 1) //selects only one category
       ->addFieldToFilter('level','4')       //selects only 3rd level categories                              
       //->addFieldToFilter('parent_id','188' ) //select only child categories of no 3                        
       // ->setOrder("level") //combined by setPage, returns the lowest level category
         ->load();

      // if the product is associated with any category
      if ($categories->count())
      foreach ($categories as $_category)
      {

      $cur_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());

      ?>

      <div class="head"><h4>Todos os produtos da coleção <strong><?=$cur_category->getName()?> (Id: <?=$cur_category->getId()?>)</strong></h4></div>
      <div class="content">
      <ol>
      <? $products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
      ->addCategoryFilter($_category)
      ->addAttributeToSelect('small_image');

       foreach ( $products as $productModel )
         {
              $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productModel->getId());
              $width=50; $height=50;
              $_imageUrl =  $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($productModel, 'small_image')->resize($width, $height);
      ?>
 <li<?php if($_product->isComposite() || !$_product->isSaleable()): ?> class="super-products"<?php endif; ?> class="product-box">
            <div class="product-images">

                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail')->resize(50) ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" width="50" height="50" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="product-details">
                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?></a>
                <!-- Price -->
            <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>          
            </div>
        </li>


      <?  }

      echo "</ol><div class=\"clear\"></div></div>";

        }

      }
      ?>
          </div>
```

Could someone please help me solving that??
Thank you in advance for your help!

Cheers,
jw

Comment: So what problem are you having right now? Are you able to retrieve the current category successfully? What output do you get?

Answer (score 2):

Tks to http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/51638/ I finally came to an answer. The following code works great in he view.html page:

```
<div class="box base-mini mini-related-items"> 
<div class="head"><h4>Todos os produtos da coleção <strong><?php echo $this->getProduct()->getCategory()->getName() ?> </strong></h4></div>
      <div class="content" style="float:left">
      <ol>

<?php                        
$cat_id = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId(); // set current category id
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat_id);
$products = $category->getProductCollection()->addCategoryFilter($category)->addAttributeToSelect('*');
?>
<?php foreach ( $products as $_product ): ?>
<li<?php if($_product->isComposite() || !$_product->isSaleable()): ?> class="super-products"<?php endif; ?> class="product-box">
            <div class="product-images">

                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail')->resize(50) ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" width="50" height="50" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="product-details">
                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?></a>
                <!-- Price -->
            <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>          
            </div>
        </li>
<?php endforeach; ?> 
</ol></div><div style="clear:both"><br /></div>
</div></div>
```